# Modificar metodo para retornar un string?

Tags: java

Buenas , Veran Tengo Este Codigo

```
 private static void Perm2(String[] elem, String act, int n, int r) {
    if (n == 0) {
        System.out.println(act);
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
            if (!act.contains(elem[i])) { // Controla que no haya repeticiones
                Perm2(elem, act + elem[i] + ", ", n - 1, r);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

y como se daran cuenta imprime todo los resultados en consola, lo que me gustaria es poder guardar todo en un solo String para poder utlizar ese String a mi conveniencia si es posible o al menos poder imprimirlo en un JOptionpanel si es que es posible claro.

De Antemano Muchas Gracias

Comment: te recomiendo que para realizar concatenaciones en ciclos o cualquier otra concatenacion de Cadenas no uses String utiliza StringBuilder en su lugar http://javahungry.blogspot.com/2013/06/difference-between-string-stringbuilder.html

Comment: Esto parece ser un algoritmo para imprimir las diferentes posibles permutaciones de las cadenas. No entiendo por qué quieres juntar todas las permutaciones en una línea. No me parece muy legible. En todo caso, te aviso que el programa no va a funcionar correctamente si los diferentes elementos tienen un parecido. Por ejemplo, si tu lista de elementos es `{"aaa", "aa", "a"}`, verás que el resultado es incorrecto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dices que te imprime todos los valores por consola pero solo te pintará cuando n==0 sea true. De todas maneras, si lo que quieres es que en vez de que te imprima por pantalla te lo almacene en un string lo puedes hacer así:

```
string result ="";  //Aquí guardaremos el resultado

private static void Perm2(String[] elem, String act, int n, int r) {
if (n == 0) {
    result = result + act; //Vamos concatenando los resultados
} else {
    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
        if (!act.contains(elem[i])) { // Controla que no haya repeticiones
            Perm2(elem, act + elem[i] + ", ", n - 1, r);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Ya tenemos el resultado en result, lo podemos imprimir o utilizar desde otro sitio.

Comment: Eres Un Crack Eso Es Justo Lo Que Quería, de echo intente algo parecido que tu solo que yo tenia así  `result+=act` y nunca hacia nada, me ayudaste demasiado muchas gracias